# how to see the value of CXX and CXXFLAG

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

before compiling my C++ program, i `export`ed the `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` from the command line.

`$ export CXX="/media/space/gcc-dist/bin/g++"`

`$ export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x"`

But now i want to see the values of `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`. How do i do that.
I'm using KUbuntu 11.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually do this on Linux systems by opening a terminal and entering

```
echo $CXX
echo $CXXFLAGS
```